# Measure of Association between two Ordinal Variables

Tags: ordinal-data, association-measure, somers-d

I have two ordinal variables. One is independent and the other one is dependent variable. I would like to test if there is monotonic relationship between these two or not. I am using Somers' d measure in SPSS.
 Now to use Somers' d measure, does it matter if more than 20% of the cells have expected frequencies below five?
 I think this assumption only applies to the Chi-square test for the nominal by ordinal variables or two nominal variables. I am not 100% sure!

Comment: Does each specimen get a rank or get categorized into an ordinal scale?  If the first, then @Lan's suggestion of the Spearman makes sense.  If the second, then something like Somer's D is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you not compute [Spearman's rank correlation coefficient?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient)