# Somers' D. Is there an assumption about sample size

Tags: somers-d

Is it possible to run Somers' D (and its accompanying significance tests) on a very small sample?  In my case, I have a 2x3 (one variable is ordinal, the other 0/1 coded) table but only 36 cases. If it is (not) okay, does anyone know the exact assumption?

PS: A similar question is asked here: [Measure of Association between two Ordinal Variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202095/measure-of-association-between-two-ordinal-variables?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's OK to do any analysis on a small sample if you completely understand the data quality and possible sample selection biases.  But it is very important to include self-contained statistical quantifications that capture the limitations of the information base used in the analysis.  In your case this can be done in the frequentist statistics setting using a compatibility interval (aka confidence interval).  For example the R `Hmisc` package `rcorr.cens` function will give you the standard error of $D_{xy}$ which can be used to get an approximate compatibility interval.

Note: *compatibility* is related to the fact that the confidence interval includes the set of $D_{xy}$ values that if null hypothesized would not be rejected at the $1 - \alpha$ level.